# How to center vertically in div link and image for ie 6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I need to put a close link and image in right of link. In IE 6 I get it all wrong:
More over i need to do that image and text be centered vertically
What i need to do:
[image: what i need]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="close-text">
<a class="text-img">close</a>
<img src="/assets/browsers/button-close.png">
</div>
```

and css (sass)

```
.close-text{
height: 26px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #b94a48;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
img{
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  float: right;
}
&:hover{
  color: #cecece;
}
.text-img{
  font: 11px arial,sans-serif;
}
```

}

How to get this working in IE 6? and all browsers?

Comment: Ah, sorry) vertical-align: middle; is my solve